# How to pass Dynamic ID to href link in Lightning web components

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to Preview and download document from LWC, From apex controller i am returning Map<> contains ID and Document name, and iteration that map data in html file and passing map.key value to href url, but dynamic is not populating in URL.

```
  <template for:each={mapData} for:item="mapkey">
                           Test: {mapkey.key}                             
                           <lightning-button-icon key={mapkey} icon-name="utility:download"  variant="bare" alternative-text="Settings"></lightning-button-icon>
                               <a key={mapkey} style="color: #000000"  href ="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/{mapkey.Key}?operationContext=S1" target="_blank" preview= "{mapkey.value}">{mapkey.value}</a>  
                       </template>
```

JS Code:

```
    .then(data => {         
  /// var conts = data;                
  console.log('data map--->'+data);
    if(data){
    // eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
    for(let key in data) {
   this.mapData.push({value: data[key], key:key}); //Here we are creating the array to show on UI.
   }      
}
})
```

Apex Code:

```
 @auraenabled
/* Method will return a Map Contains Document ID and Name */
public static Map<string,string> getUrls( string searchstr){
    Map<string,string> contdocidandtitle = new Map<string,string>();
    system.debug('searchstr'+searchstr);        
    For(Document cd :[select id,folderid,name from document where folder.name =:searchstr]){
        contdocidandtitle.put(cd.id,cd.name);            
    }
    return contdocidandtitle;
}
```

Error is:
sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/%7Bmapkey.Key%7D?operationContext=S1
in URL "mapkey.key" priniting instead of ID
Help me with valuable suggestions.

Comment: hi i declared @track mapData =[]; in my JS,  from my HTML Test: {mapkey.key}   this line priniting resepective ID from map, but it is not populating in url binding

Comment: thats because you are passing the property as a string in the href parameter, or at least thats how its interpreted as per the error message

Comment: HI Thank you for your quick response, Could you please let me know what exactly should i do in my case here. Thanks in advance

Comment: no - please refer to the duplicate post and the documentation. If you run into any issues, please open a new post and specify what problem you are facing alongside what you have tried to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?

Make below changes in HTML file

```
<template for:each={mapData} for:item="mapkey">
                       Test: {mapkey.key}                             
     <lightning-button-icon key={mapkey} icon-name="utility:download"  variant="bare" alternative-text="Settings"></lightning-button-icon>
     <a key={mapkey} href={mapkey.url} target="_blank" preview= "{mapkey.value}">{mapkey.value}</a>  
</template>
```

In JS code :

```
.then(data => {         
   if(data){
   // eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
   for(let key in data) {
    this.mapData.push({value: data[key], key:key, url : '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/' + key + '?operationContext=S1' });
   }      
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot It works like Flawlessly.

Comment: Sure. can you accept this answer and mark it.